Is "For the very reason why he had chosen the lighthouse had become almost instantly a reason for going somewhere else" a mistake?
In Aldous Huxley's Brave New World there is a sentence that seems to be a linguistic mistake. Am I right?

"When morning came, he felt he had earned the right to inhabit the lighthouse; yet, even though there still was glass in most of the
windows, even though the view from the platform was so fine. For the
very reason why he had chosen the lighthouse had become almost
instantly a reason for going somewhere else. He had decided to live
there because the view was so beautiful, because, from his vantage
point, he seemed to be looking out on to the incarnation of a divine
being."

The sentence starts with the preposition "for" which could either mean:

because of; through: she wept for pure relief.(Collins English Dictionary)

used to show a reason or cause
The town is famous for its cathedral.(Oxford Learners Dictionary)


If it's the former, the sentence could be transformed to "Because the very reason why he had chosen the lighthouse had become almost instantly a reason for going somewhere else.". It seems incorrect because "because" should be followed by some result of the thing that "because" refers to (in this case: the very reason why he had chosen the lighthouse had become almost instantly a reason for going somewhere else). But there is no reason following it afterward. If in the place of the full stop was a comma followed by "he decided to leave" I would have no problem with understanding it.
If it's the latter the sentence doesn't make sense either and it would have to be followed by "he decided to leave" even sooner, right after "For the very reason why he had chosen the lighthouse".
Also, "for" could omitted entirely "The very reason why he had chosen the lighthouse had become almost instantly a reason for going somewhere else" and I would have no problem with it.

It sounds perfectly fine to me.

It is "yes, even though..." not "yet, even though..."  in some texts.

Why bother rewriting what's ok? He said "for" (because), and it relates to an earlier thought.  For I am sure that as an author, he knew that. Authors like this don't make "linguistic mistakes". Sometimes, a copyeditor might overlook a typo or other word, but it's rare in classics like this.,

A sentence beginning with "For" in this way is an explanation or justification of something just asserted, a previous statement. The only assertion available to explain or justify is "he felt he had earned the right to inhabit the lighthouse".

How would the reason for choosing the lighthouse also be reason for leaving it? It seems a contradiction, a paradox of some kind. In the following passage Savage talks about his deserving only a sty to live in.

@TimR Exactly, "he felt he had earned the right to inhabit the lighthouse because the very reason why he had chosen the lighthouse had become almost instantly a reason for going somewhere else" doesn't make any sense.

I think the answer is to be found in the twisted logic of Savage's thoughts in the passage following  the sentence in question.

Your example simply has the following structure. No addition or omission of any word(s) performed.

Even though there still was glass in most of the windows, even though the view from the platform was so fine, yet he felt he had earned the right to inhabit the lighthouse when the morning came. ((For the very reason why he had chosen the lighthouse had become almost instantly a reason for going somewhere else.))

The "((For ~ esle.))" part, which is an adverbial clause, backs up the preceding main clause part of "yet he felt he had earned the right to inhabit the lighthouse when the morning came." and gives the particulars of why he felt like he had earned the right to inhabit the light house.
Why? It's because the lighthouse is too favorable for him to stay where he resides currently — as soon as he perceived the lighthouse as a good one he immediately decided to set out for somewhere, the lighthouse —  the indepenent/stand-alone adverbial clause beginning with 'For' is from time to time seen in literary works or formal writings. It's not regarded as grammar error at all since it's so purposely.
If you link the "((For ~ esle.))" part with the latter part sentence below, the result is terrible: a reason for going somewhere else becomes the reason for living(not going).

He had decided to live there because the view was so beautiful, because, from his vantage point, he seemed to be looking out on to the incarnation of a divine being.


The OED says "Now somewhat literary." (for conjunction 2a "...seeing that, since"). But one example is from 1968: "The days of the disc, in the pop world at least, are numbered. For soon will come the video." I guess that's mock-literary.

Another one from 2012: "The same young man went on to Rio and capered around there. More big pictures. For it is Prince Harry, out and about selling the Firm and its subsidiary, the Commonwealth."
